# using Log4J2 in Spark 2 applications to create Custom Logs

Tags: apache-spark, log4j2

I am using Spark 2 version.

My spark submit application has Log4J2 jars shaded as part of the build. The log4j.xml is placed in resources folder.

Can i create logs created using Log4J 2 API in a new file?

What do i need to do to make it work?

Comment: What currently happens when you run the code? Where exactly are you expecting log files to be created?

Answer (score 0):

create log4j.properties in the resources folder.

file content of log4j.properties

```
log4j.appender.RollingAppenderU=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppenderU.File=/Give path for cutosm log file/sparkU.log
log4j.appender.RollingAppenderU.MaxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.RollingAppenderU.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.RollingAppenderU.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RollingAppenderU.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n


# My custom logging goes to another file
log4j.logger.myLogger=INFO,RollingAppenderU

# The noisier spark logs go to file only
log4j.logger.spark.storage=INFO, RollingAppenderU
log4j.additivity.spark.storage=false
log4j.logger.spark.scheduler=INFO, RollingAppenderU
log4j.additivity.spark.scheduler=false
log4j.logger.spark.CacheTracker=INFO, RollingAppenderU
log4j.additivity.spark.CacheTracker=false
log4j.logger.spark.CacheTrackerActor=INFO, RollingAppenderU
log4j.additivity.spark.CacheTrackerActor=false
log4j.logger.spark.MapOutputTrackerActor=INFO, RollingAppenderU
log4j.additivity.spark.MapOutputTrackerActor=false
log4j.logger.spark.MapOutputTracker=INFO, RollingAppenderU
```

You can use provided log4j library come with prebuild spark

code snippet as:-

```
 import org.apache.log4j.Logger

 object customLogGenerataor {
   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val  logger:Logger  = Logger.getLogger("myLogger")
    logger.info("Read data..........!!!")
  }
}
```